# sys.prefix generates "Segmentation fault: 11" when trying to decide if I am using User for Enthought Canapy

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, scikit-learn, enthought, canopy

I read a post with this same issue, and it seems Enthought Canopy is working on the problem and will have a new version in February some time.  Can I still import packages from sources other than Canopy and use them in Canopy? I'm following the steps in Jonathan March's Guide "Make Canopy User Python be your default Python (i.e. on the PATH)".  I am following this article in preparation for installing scikit-learn. Making Canopy User Python my default Python scares me a bit, because I'm not used to setting things up on the backend, and I mostly just use Eclipse.  Can I still use Eclipse if I do this?  Anyway, I'm using Mac OS X, version 10.9.1, and when I follow his instructions:

import sys; sys.prefix

At the terminal window in a Python session, Python bombs and I get

Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: Use Anaconda and everything will work out of the box ;) It also comes with scikit-learn.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, that's just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Seems likely that you are referencing several different pythons simultaneously. Most likely culprits are PYTHONPATH or PYTHONHOME environment variables, but PATH is also an slight possibility. See:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/23665767-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-

What is the contents of these 3 environment variables? (From a terminal, type `env`).

And no, if you are nervous about making Canopy your default Python, don't! The Canopy GUI application doesn't need it, and if/when you need to access Canopy Python in Terminal, you can do so temporarily without in any way affecting the rest of your system or other pythons.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jonathan.  Anaconda seems to have what I need, without the technical hurdles.